# Where are .deb files located?

Tags: apt, deb

When we install a package in Ubuntu using `apt-get install`, where can we find the .deb files ?

I installed Python using this method but I did not find its .deb file in `/var/cache/apt/archive/`.

Comment: Yes, it is included by default, but I installed an other version of it

Comment: @SOStinks I... don't understand what you mean. Google is a search engine and the idea is that you click on the links it provides and read them. I don't see how it can be lying. In any case, yes, that was a typo but I cannot edit old comments, so I will just delete it since the answer below explains it nicely. I suspect, however, that what you saw in Google was the text of the question and not my comment.

Comment: The problem is, people want to know what they've installed onto the system, and they want a copy of THOSE deb files. Not any other deb files, but those specific ones. How do you get those debian files out of system?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

By default, apt stores the .deb files in `/var/cache/apt/archives`. If you can't find them here, you or someone else or something else(a software like Ubuntu tweak) may have run a clean-up command like `sudo apt-get clean` to clear up the .deb files. However, you can manually search all .deb files in your system by doing the following(may require superuser privileges):

```
sudo updatedb
```

This will update `locate`'s database to search for newly created/removed files, this may take a while depending upon the difference in time when the last time `updatedb` was run(it is usually run as a cron job daily) and then

```
locate *.deb
```

which will search your `/` folder recursively for all files ending with `.deb`.

Comment: Thank you Jobin. Yes, I performed the clean several times, indeed before I searched for the .deb file

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't have the debian files that i need.